# Duplicated table, values of words varying even between duplicated words. Find words only have specific value

Tags: mysql, duplicates

There is a table i work in Mysql. There are words and values. Values is Boolean like '1' or '0'. Words can repeat more than once. And their values vary. For example one "def" can be '0' while other is '1'. What i am trying to find is:

- The values only have zero values. And if there is more than once of this word take only one word.
- But, "def" has '0' value. Also '1' value. It must be only '0' values!

The table is like:

```
word value
----  -----
abc    1
abc    1
def    0
def    1
def    0
xyz    0
xyz    0
xyz    0
xxx    1
zzz    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't understand what you're trying to obtain.
Anyway I try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT word FROM your_table
WHERE value = 0
```

If you want to sort words alphabetically, you can do

```
SELECT DISTINCT word FROM your_table
WHERE value = 0
ORDER BY word
```

**EDITED** in response to user comment:
Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT word,value FROM your_table
WHERE word NOT IN
  (SELECT word FROM your_table WHERE value = 1)
```

or

```
SELECT word, SUM(value) as tot FROM your_table
GROUP by word
HAVING SUM(value) = 0
```

Comment: @user1002601: is this what you need?

Comment: No. Becuase let's assume, there is 3 "abc". And 2 of them has value of '0' and 1 of them has value of '1'. You said WHERE value = 0 and DISTINCT. There will be an "abc" = 0 in result. But there are also value of '1' in a duplicate "abc" word. I want only the ones contain '0'.

Comment: @user1002601: your answer was really unclear, let me tell you. Anyway I edited my post in response to your comment.

Comment: Yes thank you very much. But second query doesn't work. It needs to be like: "SELECT word, SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM your_table HAVING value_sum = 0 GROUP BY word"

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
select word,min(value) from table group by word;
```

which will return a 0 if a word has 0 and 1 as a value or 1 if it's only got a 1

If you specifically want only the '0' values then:

```
select word,value from table where value=0 group by word;
```

Comment: OK. After finally understanding what the OP wanted, I defer to @Marco's answer.For those who are still struggling with the original post, the OP wants only those words which have a '0' value against them and, if a word has a '1' in addition to a '0' record, discard it